# (Android) get cache size of all installed apps

Tags: android

I can only find either very old Q&As around this topic, or very incomplete ones that never really work. So, In the current Android SDK 30, is it possible at all to query the cache size of all installed apps in the device, and then display them in your own app? If yes, how? If not, which sdk should I use instead?

To be clear, I am already listing all the apps in the device (icon + name + package), I just can't find a way to fetch the information of their cache size to display next to them.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67570493/android-get-cache-size-of-all-installed-apps

Comment: check this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/49815819/11365488

Comment: getCacheDir seems targeted towards locating "this" app's cache. I'm under the impression that it cannot be used to locate and measure the cache dirs of other apps in the device. Am I wrong about this?

Comment: @Mayec - have you found any solution? please help me. I want all apps cache size

Comment: @khushbu-vadi - No, sorry. I gave up on this.